# How to replicate Excel's IFERROR in Python

Tags: python, excel, error-handling, try-catch

I am trying to translate an Excel formula into Python. The formula involves the `IIFERROR(value, value_if_error)` statement. Here is the actual formula:

```
IFERROR(IF(AND(BQ2<>"",INT(BQ2)<='C:\Users\[R_FY_Template.xlsx]Date'!$B$2),"YES", "NO"),"NO")
```

Where `'C:\Users\[R_FY_Template.xlsx]Date'!$B$2` is replaced by today's date.

My translation of a function (I need it to iterate through rows in a dataframe) that recreates this is as follows:

```
def bs_trigger(row):
try:
  if (row.PRELIM_DATE != None) & (row.PRELIM_DATE <= today):
      return "YES"
  else:
      return "NO"
except ValueError:
      return "NO"
```

On the surface using `try/except` would handle for there being an error (equivalent to `IFERROR`) and still returning a value, right? Is there some other way I could go about this or am I doing this correctly?

Comment: That seems correct to me. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that, because no error is thrown, its hard to debug. Its an issue of accuracy rather than an overt error being thrown.